# Как правильно записать запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `b1`.`balance` AS `pbalance`, `b1`.`user` AS `pname`
FROM `Tbalances` b1
LEFT JOIN `Tconnections` c1 ON (`b1`.`user` = `c1`.`user`) AND (`c1`.`lasttime` >  SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 SECOND))
LEFT JOIN `Tplayers` p1 ON `c1`.`user` = `p1`.`name`
LEFT JOIN `Tconnections` c2 ON (`p1`.`oper` = `c2`.`user`) AND (`c2`.`lasttime` >  SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 SECOND))
LEFT JOIN `Topers` o1 ON `c2`.`user` = `o1`.`name`
```

Описание, того что хотел сделать, с низу в верх:

1 В Tconnections нахожу строки всех операторов

2 В Tplayers нахожу тех игроков у которых оператор активен

3 В Tconnections нахожу строки выбранных игроков

4 В Tbalance нахожу баланс и имена игроков из выбранных, тех что активны

Показывает все строки из Tbalance , не зависимо от того кто активен, а почему не пойму?

UPD

```
SELECT `balances`.`balance` AS `pbalance`, `balances`.`user` AS `pname`
FROM `balances`
INNER JOIN `uplayers` ON `balances`.`user` = `uplayers`.`name`
LEFT JOIN `connections` ON `uplayers`.`oper` = `connections`.`user`
WHERE (`connections`.`session` = "' + SessionKey + '") AND (`lasttime` >  SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 SECOND));
```

Почему тогда сдесь я получаю правильный список игроков оператора?

Comment: Добрый день. Вы делаете `LEFT JOIN` для таблицы `Tbalances`. Т.е. все записи в таблице `Tbalances` всегда будут показаны. Если надо найти пересечения используйте `JOIN`.

Comment: @Deft во всех четырёх случаях?

Comment: убрал LEFT и заработало, только начал думать что разобрался с JOINами и вот тебе на. Дополню в вопросе другой запрос, по моему аналогичный, но он с LEFT работает, можете сказать почему?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 `LEFT JOIN` следует использовать только тогда, когда он действительно нужен, т.е. вы хотите получить из основной таблицы все записи, вне зависимости от наличия подходящих записей в другой таблице (которая справа от LEFT). Во всех остальных случаях надо использовать обычный JOIN, он же INNER

Comment: @ArtGrek13 `LEFT JOIN` в таких условия может работать, если в условии после `ON`, либо после `WHERE`, стоит условие, ограничивающее выборку к нужному результату. Но, как писал @Mike выше, в таких случаях лучше использовать `JOIN`.

Comment: @Deft то есть в первом и третьем JOINах я могу написать LEFT JOIN, потому что есть условие на активность, а во втором и в четвертом INNER JOIN?

Comment: В четвертом JOIN стоит условие связи с третьей таблицей, как только вы его сделаете INNER толку от LEFT у третьего уже не будет, он перестанет работать так, как задумано. потому что 4й inner потребует наличия записи в третьей таблице. А условие LEFT у третьего когда вы его пишете подразумевает что записи может и не быть

Comment: Вообще _всегда_ пишите обычный JOIN, только в том случае, когда вы понимаете, что хотите получить результат, даже когда в правой таблице  нет записи пишите LEFT (обычно это не более 10% случаев)

Comment: @Mike так второй пример в вопросе верен?

Comment: Нет, не верен. Условие WHERE проверяется после выполнения всех JOIN. Вы connections клеите по LEFT т.е. _хотите_ получить результат даже если в таблице connections не найдется подходящей записи. Если такой записи не найдется, то на стадии WHERE любое поле этой таблицы будет NULL. Вы же проверяете в WHERE поле из этой таблицы на явное значение, которое НЕ NULL, таким образом вы полностью уничтожаете все эффект от слова LEFT...

Comment: Кроме того, если бы оптимизатор был чуть глупее и не понял бы что LEFT не имеет смысла он бы по правилам получил бы все записи из всех таблиц, а потом выбросил все записи кроме, одной с конкретной сессией. Что повлекло бы катастрофически долгое выполнение запроса. К вашему счастью оптимизатор MySQL достаточно умный и он так не делает, однако другая СУБД или старые версии MySQL могут это сделать. А посему, повторяю в третий раз _НИКОГДА не используйте LEFT там, где он действительно не нужен_. В вашем втором запросе он _не нужен_

Comment: а JOIN и INNER JOIN это одно и тоже, верно?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Да, то же самое

Comment: Ок спасибо обоим, буду перечитывать...

Comment: Я бы предложил создать пару табличек, в одной из которых записи будут не для всех записей из первой. и просто поэкспериментировать, с разными join. вообще без условий, с условиями в ON, с частью условий в WHERE. С сухой теорией (особенно если она во всяких хитрых терминах, вроде декартовых произведений) сложно понять суть. Можете считать, что действительно усвоили, когда _чувствуете_ как любое ваше действие отразится на результате